# H2 select expression column alias

Tags: sql, select, h2, column-alias

There is H2 table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sometable (ondate DATE NOT NULL);
```

With data

```
INSERT INTO sometable VALUES ('2015-07-07');
INSERT INTO sometable VALUES ('2014-07-07');
INSERT INTO sometable VALUES ('2013-07-07');
```

I want to limit the selected data amount but **the following select doesn't work**. Why?

```
SELECT YEAR(CONVERT(ondate, TIMESTAMP)) AS yr FROM sometable WHERE yr = 2015
```

*The error message is SELECT YEAR(CONVERT(ondate, TIMESTAMP)) AS yr FROM sometable WHERE yr = 2015; Column "YR" not found; SQL statement: SELECT YEAR(CONVERT(ondate, TIMESTAMP)) AS yr FROM sometable WHERE yr = 2015 [42122-176] 42S22/42122*

Comment: You want to retrieve year from the date?

Comment: Yes, and it is retrieved. `SELECT YEAR(CONVERT(ondate, TIMESTAMP)) AS yr FROM sometable` works. But... when I add WHERE it doesn't :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't H2 specific, this will happen on many RDBMS. The `yr` column isn't part of the SELECT clause really, it is the CONVERT statement that is. If you want to do that, wrap the entire statement in a derived table and query that, or use your same clause as you do in the SELECT in your WHERE.

For example;

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT YEAR(CONVERT(ondate, TIMESTAMP)) AS yr 
FROM sometable) a WHERE a.yr = 2015
```

OR

```
SELECT YEAR(CONVERT(ondate, TIMESTAMP)) AS yr FROM sometable 
WHERE YEAR(CONVERT(ondate, TIMESTAMP)) = 2015
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer to a column alias in the where clause.

```
SELECT
YEAR(CONVERT(ondate, TIMESTAMP)) AS yr
FROM sometable
WHERE YEAR(CONVERT(ondate, TIMESTAMP)) = 2015
```

Answer (score 1):

Error is stating that column `yr` is not found because `yr` is not your column name it is just a alias.
`SQL` cannot consider alias as column name you can write this way

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(CONVERT(ondate, TIMESTAMP)) AS yr 
FROM sometable WHERE 
    YEAR(CONVERT(ondate, TIMESTAMP)) = 2015
```